# access local variable outside the *ngfor in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to access the local variable of *ngFor outside the loop but not able to. Below is the html code snippet.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let key of topicData">
<span><a title="Add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createinstruboxpanel"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></span>
</div>

<div class="tabbable-line" *ngFor="let instruKey of instrumentData">

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="createinstruboxpanel" tabindex="-1">
<button type="button" class="btn save-btn" (click)="addInstrument(instruKey.group_id)" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
</div>
```

Since i am trying to access instruKey.group_id outside the loop it is giving me undefined value. Is there any way by which i can access it outside the loop.

Comment: For you use instruKey instance it needs to be inside the for

Comment: No, there is no way, because that doesn't make any sense. Let's say your instrumentData array has 1000 elements. Which of the 1000 values should instruKey have, since it's outside the loop? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to access group_id from instrumentData since i need to send it on the click event of save button. Also I am very new to Angular, correct me if this is not a good practice.

Comment: Read my commment again, and answer the question. Which of the 1000 values should instruKey have, since it's outside the loop?

Comment: Either you can keep save for individual elements inside the loop or you can keep single save button - which will save all the elements, so no need to pass id from outside the loop. This has nothing to do with angular :)

Comment: none...........

Comment: Then what should `instruKey` refer to, when used outside of the loop?